# текст по середине блока

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста как выравнить текст в блоке и по вертикале и по горизонтали. Заранее спасибо! Чтобы в `span` с класом `button` текст был ровно по центру и вертикаль и горизонталь.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 905px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.flex2 li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
span.button1 {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
 span {
 max-width: 150px;
 max-height: 200px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-countainer">
  <ul class="flex">
    <li><span>text</span><span class="button">text</span><span></span>
      <li><span>text</span><span class="button">text</span><span></span>
        <li><span>text</span><span class="button">text</span><span></span>
          <li><span>text</span><span class="button">text</span><span></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Может быть так https://jsfiddle.net/c72quumw/

Comment: текст внутри span.button и так по центру. уточните свои стили или подробности вопроса

Comment: Для выравнивания однострочного текста по вертикали нужно задать высоту линии равную высоте блока.

Comment: а если высота блока не известна ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.flex-item {
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

как то так